# Why rhombus tilings are just piling boxes with decending restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, tiling

Suppose $H$ is a hexagon with sidelength $a\times b\times c$, and it's innner angles are all $\frac{2\pi}{3}$. Then it's well known that the rhombus tilings of $H$ is in one-to-one correspondece with plane partitions of shape $a\times b$ and largest number not exceeding $c$.

That is, if we draw a 3D graph of any tiling of $H$, it will look like piling unit boxes at the corner of the wall, but with decending conditions. This fact is quite obvious, but I still want a rigorous proof. My question is, can we give a real bijection between these two objects, rather than just saying "draw a graph and it's obvious that ..." ?

[image]

Comment: Great question! An idea: there is certainly an injection from the set of piles  to the set of rhombus tilings by taking a projection onto a plane (ignoring the details on how to define it rigorously, but that's not the interesting part). So it suffices to count both sizes and prove that they're equal. OEIS might help.

Comment: As mentioned by Dijkstra in a note that can be found [here](http://gurmeet.net/puzzles/tiling-with-calissons/), the following article, aiming to prove that any tiling has an equal number of rhombi of each orientation, asserts this correspondence without proof: G. David and C. Tomei, *The problem of the calissons*, Amer. Math. Monthly. **96** (1989), 429–431. (Dijkstra then gives a rigorous proof of that assertion, but does not touch upon the correspondence.)

Comment: An explicit formula for the number of rhombus tilings: **OEIS:** http://oeis.org/A008793 or https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9909038v1.pdf (page 1, (1.1) case $a=b=c$). Counting cube pilings translates as counting matrices with entries in $\mathbb N_{\leq n}$ whose rows and columns are weakly decreasing. (The 1-dimensional analogue is a lot easier.)

Comment: @punctureddusk Unfortunately the proof that paper refers to uses the correspondence, as is mentioned in the line after the equation.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\mathbf{R}$ is the set of rhombic tilings and $\mathbf{B}$ is the set of box pilings. That there exists a 1-1 function from $\mathbf{B}\rightarrow\mathbf{R}$ I think is quite obvious - i.e. box sides are just rhombi, therefore we have a rhombic tiling. Perhaps the more difficult part is seeing that this function is onto. Let us instead show that there is a function from $\mathbf{R}\rightarrow\mathbf{B}$, and we will have shown that there exists a bijection.

I think this becomes trivial once you look at all possible combinations at any vertex. If we show that each rhombic tiling around a vertex looks (locally) like the surface of some box pile, then we have that all vertices form a mesh of the box pile. Hence, we have found that for each rhombic tile there is a box pile.

The possible combinations are (sorry for the lack of visuals, but you can find most of these examples in the picture you provided):

1. 3 rhombi arranged top, bottom left, bottom right -> top corner of a box.
2. 3 rhombi arranged bottom, top left, top right -> top of a box (or floor) from below, right side of a box (or wall) from the left, left side a box (or wall) from the right.
3. 6 rhombi arranged as a star -> a box above, to the bottom left, to the bottom right.
4. 5 rhombi arranged with obtuse angle facing bottom -> tops of 3 boxes below to the bottom, left and right, and the adjacent sides of one box above.
5. 5 rhombi arranged with obtuse angle facing top -> tops of 3 boxes, and the sides of the two front facing boxes.
6. 5 rhombi arranged with obtuse angle facing lower left -> 2 boxes stacked to the left of vertex, and one box to the right.
7. 5 rhombi arranged with obtuse angle facing lower right -> 2 boxes stacked to the right of vertex, and one box to the left.
8. 5 rhombi arranged with obtuse angle facing upper left -> 1 box to the right and and right side of boxes (or wall) to the left and above.
9. 5 rhombi arranged with obtuse angle facing upper right -> 1 box to the left and and left side of boxes (or wall) to the right and above.
10. 4 rhombi arranged with obtuse angle above and below -> the floor or 4 boxes below.
11. 4 rhombi arranged with obtuse angle to top left, bottom right -> the left wall or 4 boxes to the left.
12. 4 rhombi arranged with obtuse angle to top right, bottom left -> the right wall or 4 boxes to the right.

And that is all the possible arrangements of rhombi around a vertex (2 permutations of 3, 3 permutations of 4, 6 permutations of 5, and 1 permutation of 6).